# Entity Framework Code First Select Item Based on Relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 2 tables that were set up with Entity Framework 6 using code first.

**Member Table**

1. MemberID
2. FirstName
3. LastName
4. Email

**Member Addresses**

1. MemberAddressID
2. Address
3. City
4. State
5. Zip
6. IsDeleted
7. MemberID

What I'm trying to accomplish is grab a member entity, and let EF auto grab the relation to Member Addresses, which so far is working fine.

What I'm stuck on is that EF is grabbing all objects from the Member Addresses table even though I've marked some of the records IsDeleted = true.

Here is my query, not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
return GenRepo.Context.Member.Where(x => x.MemberID == MemberID && x.MemberAddresses.Any(y => y.IsDeleted == false)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If I follow correctly, this would return the first `Member` object where any one of the `MemberAddress` objects has `IsDeleted == false`, but it wouldn't limit it to only return `IsDeleted == false`. It would still return all of the `MemberAddress` objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
return GenRepo.Context.MemberAddresses.Where(ma => ma.MemberID == MemberID && ma.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```

This will return all of the `MemberAddress` objects for that `Member` that aren't `IsDeleted`

Or if you want to go at it from the `Member` side perhaps you can project your results into a new object:

```
return (GenRepo.Context.Member.Where(m => m.MemberID == MemberID)
        .Select(m => new {
            MemberID = m.MemberID,
            FirstName = m.FirstName,
            LastName = m.LastName,
            Email = m.Email,
            MemberAddresses = m.MemberAddresses.Where(ma => ma.IsDeleted == false)
        })).ToList()
        .Select( m => new Member {
            MemberID = m.MemberID,
            FirstName = m.FirstName,
            LastName = m.LastName,
            Email = m.Email,
            MemberAddresses = m.MemberAddresses
        }).First();
```

I don't know of a way to filter it directly in the LINQ statement, there might be a way out there though.

**edit**
Since there are issues with projecting on to an Entity in a LINQ query, this should workaround that at little to no performance cost since the `.ToList()` is only on one entity. Plus I don't like DTOs.

Comment: After continuing with your posted answer for a day or so, this is absolutely perfect. Thanks!